# Understanding the logic with conditions using return statement python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, return

I have the following exercise from [codingbat.com](https://codingbat.com/):

*Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.*

So, when I was solving it, I've formulated a simple logic as possible, based on previously exercises.

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):

  if (negative and (a < 0 and b < 0)):
    return True
  if (a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

But this solution does not work even if I declare "*negative == True*" on the second line,
giving me this table of answers:
[Inputs and Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PHi9.png)

I can't figure out what could be wrong with the conditions, and how this logic differs from the correct answer:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b < 0)
  else:
    return ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

Also, I wished to know when it is correct to put the logical condition after the *return* statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to check which inputs give a different answer for your code vs. the existing code? Did you try to take one of those inputs, and check, **step by step** what happens in each version of the code? What exactly confuses you, after trying these things? Also: please read [ask], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We want **one** question per post, and we [do not want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/) "thanks in advance".

Comment: Think carefully about `if (negative and (a < 0 and b < 0)):`. Suppose that `negative` is true, but either `a` or `b` (or both) is positive. Will the code block be entered? Why or why note? Therefore, **what will happen next** in your code? Next, read the specification. "Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative." Therefore, **what should be returned** in the case I outlined? Do we need to do any more calculation, or do we already know?

Comment: (Hint: if I am supposed to give an answer "only if" some condition is met, can I give that answer in any other case? If I cannot give the answer `True`, what answer should I give instead?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, your program fails because when your parameter "negative" is True, yes or yes, "a" and "b" must be negative.

But in your case whenever "a" or "b" are negative it will return True, even though "negative" is True.

One way to solve your problem is to simply make sure that "negative" is False when checking that "a" or "b" are negative (This does the same as the answer to the problem, just in a different way).

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):

  if (negative and (a < 0 and b < 0)):
    return True
  if (not negative) and ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0)):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```